# How to create a program that identifies longest substring palindrome regardless of letter casing

Tags: c++

I've attempted at googling algorithms for a program that outputs the result indicated in the question. Mostly, all what I've found was algorithms that satisfied the first constraint, but did not take into account the second part (ignoring the casing of letters). Conventional functions, such as `strcmpi` (I'm using c++) requires constant characters which make it impossible to incorporate within the algorithms alluded to above. In essence, I just need an idea on how I can go about creating such a program.

Comment: The community cannot write the code for you. You need to show your efforts.  Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Conventional functions, such as strcmpi (I'm using c++) requires constant characters which make it impossible to incorporate within the algorithms alluded to above." Can you elaborate on that? Seems like a random phrase.

Comment: @bipll I meant that I've tried using all c++ built-in functions which claim to ignore case-sensitivity in their comparisons. However,  none worked. So I need some creative way of working around the issue, or an alternative function which doesn't generate any issues, and produces the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a program that identifies longest substring palindrome using your own compare function. And in that compare function if two characters are same then return true else if the difference between [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of two characters is 32 then also return true. And rest as it is.